# Ec2 instance SSH access:not able to connect after the nginx installation

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am getting a weird issue in my EC2 instance.

After the successfull creation i am able to login to server via ssh commad, but onece afte i installed the nginx , i m not able to access the server via ssh.

I am getting connection timeout error, not sure why thats happening.

```
ssh: connect to host ****.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Nginx installation stpes

sudo apt install nginx

sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'

However i can able to see the webpage via browser but not able to access the server via ssh

Comment: I don’t think AWS provided AMIs come with a firewall enabled because that’s what security groups are for. You’re probably enabling UFW and locking yourself out of the instance. If you insist on using UFW and managing two sets of firewall rules, you’ll need to open the SSH port too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to allow 'OpenSSH'

- List the application configurations that ufw knows how to work with by typing

`sudo ufw app list`

- You can enable this by typing

`sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP`

- You can verify the change by typing

`sudo ufw status`

this is from: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04#step-2-adjusting-the-firewall